# Removing newline at end of file using bash shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to remove the last newline added to the file using bash script.
I have got this - 
`truncate -s $(($(stat -c '%s' foo.txt)-1)) foo.txt`

here foo.txt the file name.
but I want to parametrize  the file name, I will pas the file name to the script and it should this remove the newline at last from that file.
Request your help on this. I do not have linux in my machine and tried using cygwin but it is giving error while running the script.

Thanks

Comment: here is example - 
<1#3#5#3
1#7#6
1#5#6#9#9>

Comment: each line is separated by new line, I tried to add but did not work,
want to remove the last new line after 1#5#6#9#9

Comment: I have a tab delimited file, each line of which is separated by newline.
I want to remove only the newline  which is after the last record in the file.
for this I have the code - 
<truncate -s $(($(stat -c '%s' foo.txt)-1)) foo.txt>

but here the file name is hardcoded as foo.txt. I want to pass the filename to the bash script as a parameter so that it will remove the last newline from that particular file.

Comment: Is newline is the only character on last line?

Comment: yes newline is the only char on last line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove last line if it is newline use this `sed`L

```
sed -i.bak '/^[[:blank:]]*$/{$d;}' foo.txt
```

Comment: hey thanks,
but when I am opening using notepad++ the file remains same. can we remove the last byte using that code and include this in a script and call the script with a parameter file name.

Comment: Show output of `tail -1 foo.txt | cat -vte`

Comment: that was the output in the console, not sure if I have done something wrong

Comment: I want to remove the newline after the last record and move up the cursor to the end of the last record. that other code is working , but I want it to parameterized with the filename. the other code mentioned by me is removing the last byte (which is for new line) from the file.

Comment: But you wrote above last line has only newline character.?

Comment: yes, 
I modified the code with parameter it worked -
<truncate -s $(($(stat -c '%s' $1)-1)) $1>